# Can I host Facebook's all.js locally?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've been noticing that sometimes my Facebook app runs slow, and when checked it was because the all.js file was not loaded from the Facebook server, so I copied the file ontp my server and tested it.

Everything seems to work fine, and actually it runs faster. My question is - do you know if there are bugs or errors in doing this?

Comment: pretty sure that's against TOS. also, you don't get updates, etc. also, your host is faster than FB? that's a really nice server you got there then :)

Comment: i dunno if the server runs faster, but it.s obvious that now the app runs faster, maybe because it doesn.t have to search for the file in another server

Comment: Maybe for you it's faster. But considering that your website will be in a server somewhere in the world, FB has much better world-balancing, world-caching, etc... I'm not sure, but I predict this will be against TOS.

Comment: I'd imagine that it's cached by the end users browser anyway so it's only obtained on first load. And they probably already have it from previous visits to the site. When you load your site check the get requests - what's the code for the .js file the second time round? It's probably 304, not modified and so not (re)loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that now you're shifting a dependency, and by extension the maintenance of that dependency to your local application. If it's hosted on Facebook's servers, they can update it to fix bugs or add features.

If it's taking a long time to load, you should bring it up on their support forums

Comment: An example of where local is desired is this: Using the the PHP SDK and the JS together, Facebook updated the cookie format in both breaking a site I had until I found out and had time to pull down the updated PHP SDK.  Keeping these in sync in the real world is impossible unless you have local control of both versions.

Comment: I wouldn't say impossible, as long as you only cache it for ~1hour (or more depending on the importance to your site) it should sync up within a reasonable timeframe. What i ended up doing is pointing the script tag to a local /path/to/all.js and using url rewrite to point that to a server side script that checks the cache for a current file, and downloads from facebook if it's not present. all.js today is taking >20s to load, but sharethis.com is having similar problems (buttons.js >40s) so i'm taking measures to make sure neither will affect page loading time in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Your page has to load the all.js file in any case.

- Facebook servers should be faster than the server which host your
  website. So, theoretically loading the js file from facebook should
  be faster.
- A better approach would be to cache the file for some time. This will make the page loads       after the initial one much, much faster.
- As people have mentioned, the all.js file is updated constantly with bug-fixes etc. So, it is always better to get the newest version of the file instead of manually updating it on your server after some time.

Answer (score 2):

You can have some problems when the facebook update API. You will need to regularly and frequently (every 5 min?) update the file.

Comment: No! I mean, you need to check it every 5 minutes and update if it has changed. If the API changes without backwards compatibility, your application will not work for some time.